# How can I multiply all values in a column based on a column from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I couldn't quite find an answer for this so I apologize if it has been answered before.

Say I have two tables:

```
Table 1
+--------+----+
| Number | ID |
+--------+----+
|      1 | AA |
|      5 | BB |
|     10 | CC |
|      2 | DD |
|     20 | EE |
+--------+----+

Table 2:
+----+--------+
| ID |  Name  |
+----+--------+
| AA | Cat    |
| BB | Dog    |
| CC | Bird   |
| DD | Fish   |
| EE | Monkey |
+----+--------+
```

I want to multiple the Number column by a value (for example increase it by 50%) but I want to modify only the ones whose Name = 'Dog' only.

I tried something like this for my code:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET number = number*1.50
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 USING (ID)
WHERE name = 'Dog';
```

But it's not working.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

It seems that I have found my answer:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET number = number*1.50
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM Table2 WHERE name = 'Dog');
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
SET t1.number = t1.number*1.50
WHERE t2.name = 'Dog';
```